# Unable to get mypy to accept code which works correctly; generics appear to be the problem

Tags: mypy

The following program is self-documenting. It gives the correct results, but it fails typechecking with mypy --strict.

Maybe there's a bug in mypy. More likely, my type annotations are incorrect. Any ideas?

```py
"""
This code shows a technique for creating user-defined infix operators.

The technique is not my invention. However, I would like to have an implementation that:
a) I understand
b) type-checks with mypy --strict.

This code allows any two-argument function to be called as an operator, using the syntax:
    leftArgument <<functionName>> rightArgument
... for the avoidance of doubt, << and >> are literally present in the code.
"""

from typing import Callable, Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")
U = TypeVar("U")
V = TypeVar("V")

class WithLeft(Generic[T, U, V]):
    def __init__(self, func, left: T) -> None:
        self.func = func
        self.left = left
    def __rshift__(self, right: U) -> V: 
        return self.func(self.left, right)
class WithRight(Generic[T, U, V]):
    def __init__(self, func, right: U) -> None:
        self.func = func
        self.right = right
    def __rlshift__(self, left: T) -> V: 
        return self.func(left, self.right)
class Op(Generic[T, U, V]):
    def __init__(self, func) -> None:
        self.func = func
    def __rlshift__(self, left: T) -> WithLeft[T, U, V]: 
        return WithLeft(self.func, left)
    def __rshift__(self, right: U) -> WithRight[T, U, V]: 
        return WithRight(self.func, right)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print("Define the operator <<add>>, which adds two ints.")
    @Op
    def add(a: int, b: int) -> int:
        return a + b
    print("Demonstrate that it works.")
    print(f"{12 <<add>> 44} correctly prints {12 + 44}")
    print('Previous line gives error from mypy:')
    print('\tUnsupported operand types for << ("int" and "Op[<nothing>, <nothing>, <nothing>]")')
    print()
    print("Define the operator <<compose>>, which composes two functions.")
    P = TypeVar("P")
    Q = TypeVar("Q")
    R = TypeVar("R")
    @Op
    def compose(left: Callable[[Q], P], right: Callable[[R], Q]) -> Callable[[R], P]:
        return lambda x: left(right(x))
    print("Demonstrate that it works.")
    from math import (
        cos, # angle in radians, not degrees
        log # base e, not base 10
    )
    logcos: Callable[[float], float] = log <<compose>> cos
    print('Previous line gives two errors from mypy:')
    print('\tUnsupported operand types for << ("Callable[[SupportsFloat, SupportsFloat], float]" and "Op[<nothing>, <nothing>, <nothing>]")')
    print('\tUnsupported operand types for >> ("WithLeft[<nothing>, <nothing>, <nothing>]" and "Callable[[SupportsFloat], float]")')
    print()
    print(f"{logcos(1)} correctly prints {log(cos(1))}")
```

*Stackoverflow doesn't like this post because it is mostly code.
So I'll repeat the explanation from the code. No need to read this again!
This code shows a technique for creating user-defined infix operators.
The technique is not my invention. However, I would like to have an implementation that:
a) I understand
b) type-checks with mypy --strict.
This code allows any two-argument function to be called as an operator, using the syntax:
leftArgument <> rightArgument
... for the avoidance of doubt, << and >> are literally present in the code.*

Comment: might well be an inference bug. It works if I remove `@Op`, use `comp: Op[Callable[[float], float], Callable[[float], float], Callable[[float], float]] = Op(compose)` and `log <<comp>> cos`

Comment: Joel, thank you for your response, but it doesn't solve the problem. Defining comp in the way you suggest has the effect that comp can only be used to compose float->float functions. This should not be the case; comp should be able to compose any pair of functions provided that the result type of the right function is the same as the argument type of the left function.

Comment: yes, I realise that. What I mean is that it may solve the problem by determining it's a bug in mypy rather than a bug in your code